# web services on a dedicated port within an ASP.net web site

Tags: asp.net, web-services

Is it possible to have a web service within an ASP.NET forms web site run on a different port, sort of like how SSL has a dedicated port?

The service needs to see the app_code folder in the existing site and of course app_data.

Any links to articles or tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have several different ports bound to a website in IIS, however if you bind that port, it will work on the whole website. You can't bind a port specifically to a directory within a site.

So you can have a secondary port (ex: 8080) added along with a hostname through the website bindings in IIS.

If you don't want to have the rest of the site (that's not the web service) to respond to the secondary port, you would have to do it through either code, or configuration.

Comment: Is there a way to redirect a user that enters on say port 8080 to a subdirectory, if my main page at port 80 is a logon page?

Comment: I guess that is what I am asking, for a little help on restricting through code or configuration. I would think configuration would be fastest and easiest.

Comment: I guess the simple answer would be to catch the Request.Url object when a user visits. Something like if(Request.Url.Port==8080){Response.Redirect("/myservice/");}